# AMFPHP & PHP - Return xml data with tags. Do not want

Tags: php, xml, tags, amfphp

I'm using the simplexml extentsion and AMFPHP to send xml data to flash.

Say I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<people>
  <person>
   <name>bob</name>
  </person>
</people>
```

And I load it in with `simplexml_load_file()`.
When I do this:

```
$name = $xml->person[0]->name;
return $name;
```

it returns `"<name>bob</name>"`.
Why is it returning the tags? When I do this with just php and not AMFPHP it works fine.

Comment: Well it seems I've fixed this with strip_tags()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanna know the answer to this too

Ok, i found out how to solve this :

You basically have to type it to a string, float, double, int, or whatever you need...

---

$xml = simplexml_load_file(XML_FILE_LOCATION);

$start = (double)$xml->layer[2]['start'];

//$title = (string)$xml->layer[2]['title'];

return $start;